# Loop through a list of identifiers to load corresponding excel files?

Tags: r, excel

I can import a column of unique identifiers into R as an object. There is an excel file with a matching name for each identifier (around 500). I am trying to write a loop to go through all of these unique IDs and load the corresponding excel.

what I tried is:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(pi)){
read_excel()
}
```

Update:
so just to clarify because I don't think I provided adequate examples.

I have an excel column which consists of about 500 unique IDs, each of which is a series of 11 numbers or so. For each ID, I have an excel file with a matching name. All the excel files are in the same folder. For each unique ID, I would like to open up the file with a matching name, and retrieve specific cells, ie the bottom and top values in a particular column, the maximum value or the mean of another column, etc.

Where "pi" is the object which should be a vector of the unique IDs. I'm not sure how to complete this. Alternative methods of solving this problem are welcome. Realistically, I am just trying to retrieve specific values from the excel, ie first and last values in a certain column, maximum and mean of another column etc.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your Excel data? This is doable but hard to write code without seeing the data. Do you want a single dataframe with merged data from all of your Excel files as the output?

Comment: Hello Jamdiel. Welcome to Stackoverflow. It will be easier to help you if you provide more information about the identifiers and how they relate to the file names.  Ideally, review [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your post.

Answer (score 1):

Since the original post didn't provide data, I will illustrate one technique where we use a vector of id numbers to generate file names to read multiple spreadsheets associated with [Basic Pokémon stats](https://github.com/lgreski/pokemonData) for generations 1 - 8 of Pokémon.

To make the example completely reproducible, I maintain a zip file with this data on GitHub which we can download and load into R.

We will use the `sprintf()` function to create the file names, because `sprintf()` allows us to not only add the directory information needed to locate the files, as well as format the numbers with leading zeroes, which are required to generate the right file names.

Instead of a `for()` loop we will use `lapply()` along with an anonymous function to create the file names and read them as Excel files with `readxl::read_excel()`.

```
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/PokemonXLSX.zip",
               "PokemonXLSX.zip",
               method="curl",mode="wb")
unzip("PokemonXLSX.zip",exdir="./pokemonData")
library(readxl)
# create a set of numbers to be used to generate 
generationIds <- 1:8
spreadsheets <- lapply(generationIds,function(x) {
     # use generation number to create individual file name
     aFile <- sprintf("./PokemonData/gen%02i.xlsx",x)
     data <- read_excel(aFile)
     })
```

At this point the object `spreadsheets` is a list with eight elements, one corresponding to each generation of Pokémon (i.e one element per spreadsheet).

We can combine the seven files with `rbind()`, and then print the last few rows of the resulting data frame.

```
pokemon <- do.call(rbind,spreadsheets)
tail(pokemon)
```

...and the result:

```
> tail(pokemon)
# A tibble: 6 x 13
     ID Name  Form  Type1 Type2 Total    HP Attack Defense Sp..Atk Sp..Def
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   895 Regi… NA    Drag… NA      580   200    100      50     100      50
2   896 Glas… NA    Ice   NA      580   100    145     130      65     110
3   897 Spec… NA    Ghost NA      580   100     65      60     145      80
4   898 Caly… NA    Psyc… Grass   500   100     80      80      80      80
5   898 Caly… Ice … Psyc… Ice     680   100    165     150      85     130
6   898 Caly… Shad… Psyc… Ghost   680   100     85      80     165     100
# … with 2 more variables: Speed <dbl>, Generation <dbl>
```

### Spotlight: accessing the files from disk

To isolate the downloaded files, we use the `exdir=` argument on `unzip()` to write the unzipped files to a subdirectory of the R working directory.

We can access files in this subdirectory by adding `./pokemonData/` to their file names. The `.` in this syntax references the current directory.

We can illustrate how the filenames are created with the following code.

```
theFiles <- lapply(generationIds,function(x) {
        # use generation number to create individual file name
        aFile <- sprintf("./pokemonData/gen%02i.xlsx",x)
        message(paste("current file is: ",aFile))
        aFile
})
```

...and the output:

```
> theFiles <- lapply(generationIds,function(x) {
+         # use generation number to create individual file name
+         aFile <- sprintf("./pokemonData/gen%02i.xlsx",x)
+         message(paste("current file is: ",aFile))
+         aFile
+ })
current file is:  ./pokemonData/gen01.xlsx
current file is:  ./pokemonData/gen02.xlsx
current file is:  ./pokemonData/gen03.xlsx
current file is:  ./pokemonData/gen04.xlsx
current file is:  ./pokemonData/gen05.xlsx
current file is:  ./pokemonData/gen06.xlsx
current file is:  ./pokemonData/gen07.xlsx
current file is:  ./pokemonData/gen08.xlsx
```

One can identify the R working directory from within RStudio with the `getwd()` function. On my MacBook Pro, I get the following result.

```
> getwd()
[1] "/Users/lgreski/gitrepos/datascience"
>
```

Comment: Tyvm for your answer. I have tried to use your code, but changing the generationIDs to a suitable length ie around 500. For the next part, the path you provide is "./PokemonData/gen%02i.xlsx". How can I change that to read all the files I have? The files I have are all named as a series of 11(I think?) numbers. I do have an excel column with all these numbers/unique IDs if that helps. I believe/hope that if I figure this bit out your solution will work perfectly for me?? Thank you so much for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: @jamdiel - Please update your question to include the following: 5 - 10 of the numbers used to name your spreadsheets, and the path to the directory where these files are stored on disk. I'll also update my answer to explain how the code generates the file names that are used with `read_excel()`.